# Using a cmd / batch file to get all the files recursively modified or created after a certain date

Tags: windows, file, directory, cmd

I am trying to get all the files in an entire directory structure that has been created or modified after a certain date:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-7* delims=/: " %I in (`dir/tc/o-d/s gstmp\*yell*.tif ^
     ^| findstr 2010`) do  (
        if "%K%I%J %N %L%M" GEQ "20100806 PM 0457"  (
            echo.   [ %K-%I-%J %L:%M %N    %P. ]
        )
 )
```

I got this genius script from Stack Overflow question *[Batch File: Iterate Over Files Modified Since a Given Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479662/batch-file-iterate-over-files-modified-since-a-given-date/3481067#3481067)*.

I changed `gstmp\*yell*.tif` to be just `*`, because I want to see all the files.

Unfortunately, it is not working for me.

It echos nothing at all. What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: @enzotib oops! my fault i will remove it

Comment: Do you have files that are named '<something>Yell<something>.tif` in your folder? (That's the file mask in the `dir` statement.) If so, are there also files in that list that contain `2010` in the output of the `dir` statement? If not, the batch file will echo nothing at all, because you have nothing to echo. (You also seem to have missed a few `%` characters in the `if` statement as well.)

Comment: @KenWhite ken thanks so much for your reply. i changed gstmp\*yell*.tif to be just * because i want to see all the files; however, i didnt realize about the 2010, i will get rid of ^| findstr 2010`  , btw what are the carets for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: Create a dummy directory
MD c:\dummy
XCOPY /L /s /d:04-01-2013 c:\startdir c:\dummy >u:reportfile.txt

:: Way the second
SET "line="
DEL u:\reportfile2.txt 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%i  IN (
 'XCOPY /L /s /d:04-01-2013 c:\startdir c:\dummy'
 ) DO CALL :output "%%i"

:: Delete the dummy directory
RD /s /q c:\dummy

GOTO :eof

:output
IF DEFINED line ECHO %line% >>u:reportfile2.txt
SET line=%~1
GOTO :eof
```

Here are two ways:

The `XCOPY` lists all files created/modified after the date specified in mm-dd-yyyy format, because each one would be copied to the dummy empty directory created. The /L only `LISTS` the files that would be copied.

The first method adds a line reporting the filecount. The second method suppresses that output. Method 2 has its faults - it's more complicated (obviously) and some strange filenames may be corrupted (this can be overcome if really necessary...). If you're using sensible filenames it'll do the job...