# Delete file wit certain date- Batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i would like to delete file with certain date  - 09.02.2014 from my folder. 
My command `del Data\XXX\YYY\*.* /D -090214` doesn´t work.  There should be more files with  todays date or with date 08.02.2014 and i would  to delete just file from 9.2.2014.

Any advice?

Comment: "File with a certain date" - Does this mean file name? File creation? File modified?

Comment: Hello, it means date of modification

Comment: It may help to look at this question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479662/batch-file-iterate-over-files-modified-since-a-given-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

cd /d C:\data\xxx\yyy
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /tw') do (
  for /f "tokens=1" %%b in ("%%~ta") do (
    if "%%b" EQU "09/02/2014" echo del %%~nxa
  )
)
```

Remove the Echo after you have verified the correct file is selected.